# Getting value from ng-repeat in protractor test case

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I want to add two counts in the protractor testcase from ng-repeat .But I am unable to fetch the count object via repeater.

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="act in actives">
 <div>
  <input id="checkbox-active" ng-model="act.checked" 
    ng-change="chooseActive(actInact)"/> {{actInact.name}} 
 </div>
 <div><span id="active-count">{{actInact.count}}</span></div>
</div>
```

test.spec

```
this.getStateCount = function () {
    var item = element.all(by.repeater('activeInactive in activeInactives'));
        console.log("item"+item[0].count);
        console.log("item"+item[0]);

    item.getText().then(function(text){
    console.log("text1+txt2"+text[0]+text[1]);
    })
    };
```

gives active 1  inactive 2 in console.
when I tried

```
console.log("item"+item[0].count); gives undefined
```

and exception is thrown. 
and item is coming as object object.

Comment: In HTML it is 'act in actives' but you have used 'activeInactive in activeInactives'. Besides, per the example https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater, you can get the value by using `element.all(
    by.repeater('activeInactive in activeInactives').column('actInact.count'))`

Comment: `count` is a method, so you need to use it as `.count()`